# Module with Main dispatcher is missing

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm trying to make a background call to my local database and update the UI with the results using coroutines.
Here is my relevant code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.Dispatchers.IO
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.Dispatchers.Main
import kotlin.coroutines.experimental.CoroutineContext
import kotlin.coroutines.experimental.suspendCoroutine

class WarehousesViewModel(private val simRepository: SimRepository)
: BaseReactViewModel<WarehousesViewData>(), CoroutineScope {

private val job = Job()

override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = job + Main

override val initialViewData = WarehousesViewData(emptyList())

override fun onActiveView() {
    launch {
        val warehouses = async(IO) { loadWarehouses() }.await()
        updateViewData(viewData.value.copy(items = warehouses))
    }
}

private suspend fun loadWarehouses(): List<Warehouse> =
    suspendCoroutine {continuation ->
        simRepository.getWarehouses(object : SimDataSource.LoadWarehousesCallback {
            override fun onWarehousesLoaded(warehouses: List<Warehouse>) {
                Timber.d("Loaded warehouses")
                continuation.resume(warehouses)
            }

            override fun onDataNotAvailable() {
                Timber.d("No available data")
                continuation.resume(emptyList())
            }
        })
    }
}
```

My problem is that I get a runtime exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with Main dispatcher is missing. Add dependency with required Main dispatcher, e.g. 'kotlinx-coroutines-android'
```

I already added these to my gradle:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.30.1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:0.26.0'
```

I'm a bit new to this, can someone help me?

Comment: use the same versions

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Using just the kotlinx-coroutines-android version solves the problem.

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:0.30.1'
```

Comment: `kotlinx-coroutines-core` is a transitive dependency of `kotlinx-coroutines-android` and the proper solution is to remove it.

Comment: Good catch Marko!  Just to clarify, Marko means remove `kotlinx-coroutines-core`, it's included in `kotlinx-coroutines-android`

Comment: To be use in Kotlin 1.3 must use this implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.2.1'

Comment: implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.3' - is the most current if anyone wants to save a few seconds.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I am confused. It is NOT an Android project, but a plain Kotlin console project (the one that prints "hello world" in the command prompt), and I have added `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.6.0` as another answer had suggested, and I encountered this runtime error when trying to use `Dispatchers.Main`. So, I should use `kotlinx-coroutines-android` even if it is not an Android project? `kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm` has been deprecated and should no longer be used?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I have tried switching to Android version, but it threw a new runtime exception: NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/Looper

Comment: @DamnVegetables Indeed, don't try to use either `kotlinx-coroutines-android` or `Dispatchers.Main` outside of an Android application.

Answer (score 18):

You may be missing some **Proguard rules**.

I had the same problem in release build and solved it by adding the following rules:

```
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler {}
-keepclassmembernames class kotlinx.** {
    volatile <fields>;
}
```

from https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/kotlinx-coroutines-android/example-app/app/proguard-rules.pro

Comment: That was it for my case. I've added all of the keeps form the GitHub page you've provided. Thank you very much!

Comment: The GitHub page linked is no longer available, 404's for me

Comment: It doesn't matter cren90 . I want to share as example. You can simply follow what I mentioned

Comment: Can rather put it in `consumer-rules.pro` if the module is a library

Answer (score 11):

Use both Core and Android dependency

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.6'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.6'
```

Comment: as pointed below the accepted answer, using only the android is enough

Answer (score 10):

If you're facing this problem with coroutines version 1.3.8, add this rule in your `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory {*;}
```

Comment: I run into this as well and indeed seems like the `AndroidDispatcherFactory` was not deobfuscated properly. With this in the proguard rules it works

Answer (score 4):

```
./gradlew assembleDebug --rerun-tasks
```

fixes it if the above answers don't work for you (because you already had the required dependencies and you are using R8 which does not need the proguard rules).

Comment: I've just change for my flavor and all right! thanks

Answer (score 4):

"core" is transitive dependency of "android" version in current version of "kotlinx-coroutines" so only use "android"

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just an additional hint if anyone tries the solutions from above and they didn't work.

For me, `--no-build-cache` didn't help. Instead, a rule in `proguard-rules.txt` did the job:

```
-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.android.** {*;}
```

My setup is `kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9`, no `kotlinx-coroutines-core` (I removed it as it turned out to be unnecessary), Kotlin 1.3.72, and Gradle 3.2.1.

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed by doing both version same
**'kotlinx-coroutines-android' and ensure it has the same version as 'kotlinx-coroutines-core'**

```
// Coroutines
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.5'//same as coroutines-android
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5"//same as coroutines-core
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, in my case keeping `minifyEnabled true` was causing the issue. but to achieve the obfuscation it was mandatory for me to keep the `minifyEnabled true` on the release build. So I did the following changes.

```
//keep only 
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.8'
```

in your proguard-rules.pro add

```
-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory {*;}
```

I also required to add the **model classes used for API call via retrofit** in the proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class com.example.test.login.data.model.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.example.test.login.data.model.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this error due to enabled proguard

```
-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory {*;}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler {}
-keepclassmembernames class kotlinx.** {
   volatile <fields>;
}
```

Add above rules in proguard-rules.pro