# Crash on app only on my computer, how to reset everything

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am facing with a specific and big problem. On the app, one guy in my team fix a Crash but when I pull his commit, I am the only one who still has the crash (we tried on 4 - 5 different computer) and we dont understand why. I tried to do different things like :

```
- Clean project and rebuild
- Sync project with Gradle
- delete an checkout the repository
- delete and reinstall Android studio
- delete my .gradle on the project
```

but nothing changed... I still have a crash...

Do you know what can I do to resolve it. 
If not, the last chance will be to reset the computer but I dont want to that.
Thank you for your help.

NB : Error that I get

```
Module with the Main dispatcher is missing. Add dependency providing the Main dispatcher, e.g. 'kotlinx-coroutines-android'
```

Comment: Post the error that appears in Logcat.

Comment: Also identify where you are running, on device or emulator and if you tested the app delete and reinstall or just install over existing.

Comment: Will you delete this question too after getting an answer, like you did with the other question I answered yesterday? It is very uncourteous to silently delete a question after receiving an answer. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58148516/getdimensionpixelsize-not-working-on-set-padding/58148918#58148918 )

Comment: @Enselic, Oh I am sorry, I didnt see that you answer that, I removed this because finally getDimenPixel work, I didnt expect I had an answer

Comment: @L2_Paver I have this following error : Module with the Main dispatcher is missing. Add dependency providing the Main dispatcher, e.g. 'kotlinx-coroutines-android'

Comment: @MorrisonChang I tried on different emulator, and on my device. and i reinstall everything except my computer.

Comment: compare your build.gradle(Project and Module) on your team and see what your missing. Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677638/module-with-main-dispatcher-is-missing

Comment: @L2_Paver we did , I also delete my project and clone but still have the same problem.

Comment: try posting your build.gradle(Project and Module) here.